# how to create a pointy button on android?

Tags: android, xml, button

How can I create a pointy button like iPhone back button in Android XML ?

[image]

I want to create using like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#f8bb49"
                android:endColor="#f7941d"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#8c8382" />
            <corners.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have an image you can work with. Read the docs on 9-patches to set margins and resizable areas.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: Your shape has 5 corners. The built int shapes are rectangle, oval, line and ring. You can still use your selector, just generate different versions of your 9-patch drawable graphic asset.

Answer (score 1):

Path and PathShape can build whatever you want. By layering a couple together and using a gradient fill you can create the 3D effect (recessed) effect.

However, you will need a class that you can use to create a drawable reference if you want to be able to use an XML definition.  Sorry I have not worked out the exact code, but it's something I'm planning to do (which is how I found your question).

Answer (score 0):

Create image like that and use **ImageButton** instead of Button 
and , use this property for ImageButton

```
android:background="@drawable/createdimage"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this for the following back button

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1cySRpqElgyTkptOFpQa3NsdDQ

using the XML files:

**left_arrow.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item >
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:toDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="89%"
            android:pivotY="-22%" >
            <shape 
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="@color/calendarOrange" android:width="3dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/drakBlue" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

**button_body.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:left="-4dp">
        <shape   android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="@color/calendarOrange" android:width="3dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/drakBlue" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Getting them together**:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    >
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/left_arrow"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        >
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button_body"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
    >

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="22dp"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

PS: *You might need to change the **android:pivotX** and **android:pivotY** parameters depending on your conteiner layout*